# Php как расшифровать символы

Tags: php

```
\u0420\u0430\u0431\u043e\u0442\u0430\u0435\u0442 \u043d\u0430 \u0442\u0435\u0445\u043d\u043e\u043b\u043e\u0433\u0438\u0438
```

Как их расшифровать? или хотя бы значения найти где?

Comment: Это не шифр, а обычные Unicode-последовательности.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev ,  так как их привести в нормальный вид?

Comment: `Работает на технологии`. Декодировано с помощью http://2cyr.com/decode/?lang=ru

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое, что пришло в голову:

```
$str = json_decode('{"str": "\u0420\u0430\u0431\u043e\u0442\u0430\u0435\u0442 \u043d\u0430 \u0442\u0435\u0445\u043d\u043e\u043b\u043e\u0433\u0438\u0438"}');
var_dump($str);
```

Результат:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
  ["str"]=>
  string(42) "Работает на технологии"
}
```

**UPD:** [Sergey Rufanov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/490545/php-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B#comment576518_490549) подсказал, что можно без обертки:

```
json_decode('"' . $text . '"')
```

Comment: Можно и без обертки. Просто `json_decode('"' . $text . '"')` :). PHP не важно отсутствие корня в JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Это Unicode-последовательность.

В зависимости от того, каким образом вы получаете этот код, можно использовать тот или иной способ, например онлайн сервис по расшифровыванию Юникода, к примеру [вот такой](http://unicode.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php).

А может это вы получаете ответ `json` и отправитель его закодировал с помощью [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php)
Тогда можно расшифровать данный ответ обратной функцией [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php)

А если это просто строка, то можно сделать функцию по определению магии, скрытой внутри и пользоваться ей:

```
$test = '\u0420\u0430\u0431\u043e\u0442\u0430\u0435\u0442 \u043d\u0430 \u0442\u0435\u0445\u043d\u043e\u043b\u043e\u0433\u0438\u0438';


function replace_unicode_escape_sequence($match) {
    return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $match[1]), 'UTF-8', 'UCS-2BE');
}

function unicode_decode($str) {
    return preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-f]{4})/i', 'replace_unicode_escape_sequence', $str);
}

echo unicode_decode($test);
```